# How to create webservice for online game

Tags: web-services, actionscript-3, flash

I created a game in flash, for **android**(I know flash is dead, but was the only platform I knew how to code a game). It's based on matches, I did the AI and the game works very well offline.

But now I want to make it online and I never developed anything for web, like websites, webservers. I do not even know what SOAP, REST and this methodologies are.

So what do I need to learn to develop something like this? Here are the requirements :

- I want to create a "room" with your facebook friends that are online in the moment.
- In this "room" you can invite them to play a match.
- The information that is passed client to client is only two points in the cartesian plane(e.g., {(1,2), (3,5)}) and the information that the game may have ended.

> It's important to notice that the server must hold connections from
>   cellphones. The information passed is from cellphone to cellphone.

**Develop the whole game in another language or platform is not an option. This is my first game that will be published, so its more like an learning exercise. I dont know PHP nor Python, but I can learn it.**

Thanks.

Comment: I suggest you post this question in PHP or python section, because your question's topic is website programming not actionscript3 .

Comment: Don't take those down-votes personally. Your first mistake is saying "Flash is dead" when it isn't (ie: shows lack of research). Secondly your game involves Facebook user accounts so you need the **[Facebook SDK](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/games/articles/getting-started-with-facebooksdk-actionscript3.html)**. Your cellphone point is confusing... the game runs on your server, right? FBook server acts as a middle-man (via SDK) between your game and updating the FB users on game progress, right? So whats the big deal with what device type is online??

Comment: Thank you @VC.One, the point is, I need to hang a connection between two players(two cellphones) to pass information between them(but the game itself will run locally on android), like I said before, two coordinates. In my mind I can use a webservice to make this work. I only want to pass those coordinates when necessary(like 1 requisition for 2 seconds). And I really appreciate your help, you were the only one that really tried to help me in a gentle way.

Comment: No worries.. Also before involving an external webservice or Facebook, you should consider a **Peer to Peer** method as an option of communicating between two phones (like how a Skype or chat app would do it, is that what you mean?). See if these **[Google Results](https://www.google.com/webhp?hl=en#hl=en&q=as3+peer+to+peer+%22android%22)** are along the lines of what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

there is a service called Flox (https://www.flox.cc/docs/getting-started) which has a AS3 integration, take a look at it, may help you